# MYSQL concatenating large string

Tags: mysql, database

I have a web crawler that saves information to a database as it crawls the web. While it does this, it also saves a log file of its actions, and any errors it encounters to a log field in a mysql database (field becomes anywhere from 64kb to 100kb. It accomplishes this by concatenating (using the mysql CONCAT function).

This seems to work fine, but I am concerned about the cpu useage / impact it has on the mysql database. I've noticed that the web crawling is performing slower than before I implemented saving the log to the database.

I view this log file from a management webpage, and the current implementation seems to work fine other than the slow loading. Any recommendations for speeding this up, or implementation recommendations?

Comment: Have you tried using a programming-language-native concatenation function?

Comment: Do you mean concatenate locally, and then save to the database all at once at the end? I would do that, but I use the log to monitor the status of the crawler.

Comment: If you're using the database CONCAT function, don't you already have to save it to the database all at once?

Comment: No, I save to the database one line at a time, concatenating the new line to the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading 100kb strings into memory numerous time then write them to disk via a db.  Of course your going to experience slowdown!  Every part of what you are doing is going to task memory, disk, and cpu (especially if memory usage hits the system max and you start swapping to disk). Let me count some of the ways your going to possibly decrease overall site performance:

1. Sql connections max out and back up as the time to store 100kb records increases time a single process holds a connection
2. Webserver processes eat up free process pool and max out and take longer to free up because they have to wait on db connections to free.
3. Web server processes begin to bloat and take more memory each, possibly more than the system can handle without swapping.  This is compounded by using the max. Umber of processes due to #2
4. ... A book could be written on your situation.

Comment: I'm aware that what I am doing is slow, and a bad idea, which is why I made the post. I'm looking for recommendations on how to improve this.

Comment: @xur17 there is no easy answer to give...  Provide some more details in your question regarding: server OS, web server your using, database your using, whether or not the DB is on the localhost or another machine, amount of memory you have for system, average size of memory for a web server process, maximum number of web server processes/threads you allow, maximumn number of DB connections you allow, and ballpark time for a simple select query on DB to run vs. time a 100Kb single insert takes on an unloaded system.  Then that and a big cup of coffee and we've got something to start with.